# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject loading data types but not data values

Tags: c#, json, winforms, serialization, deserialization

My program gives the user the option to serialize a certain list `List<Position>ListPosition` that stores the data from the class Position. It does serialize pretty well and it sorta looks like the following

```
{
    "PosZ": 0,
    "PosX": 749,
    "PosY": 208,
    "Agent": {
      "IsEdgeTree": false,
      "ThisTreesCreator": null,
      "Type": 0,
      "Colour": "Green",
      "Dimension": 25
    }
  },
  {
    "PosZ": 0,
    "PosX": 724,
    "PosY": 183,
    "Agent": {
      "IsEdgeTree": false,
      "ThisTreesCreator": {
        "IsEdgeTree": false,
        "Position": {
          "PosZ": 0,
          "PosX": 749,
          "PosY": 208
        },
        "ThisTreesCreator": null,
        "Type": 0,
        "Colour": "Green",
        "Dimension": 25
      },
      "Type": 0,
      "Colour": "Green",
      "Dimension": 25
    }
  },
```

These are just a few examples.

The bit that is giving me problems is when I deserialize it.

When I inspect the bit of code that converts it  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Position>>(JsonString);`, everything reads fine but, when I equal it to the List I am trying to dump the data to AKA the same list the serialized data comes from but empty, the data doesn't load and I'm left with the correct structure but no values.

[Values not showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzUHT.png)

To Deserialize, I call the following method from another Windows Forms:

```
public static void Deserialize()
        {
            if (Directory.Exists("Serialized"))
            {
                var FileName = "Serialized/PositionsSerialized_4.json";
                var JsonString = File.ReadAllText(FileName);                
                ListPositions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Position>>(JsonString);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("There's no directory");
        }
```

I would really appreciate some help. If more information is needed, be sure to request it in the comments.
Thank you for your time.

```
public class Position
    {
        public static int MaxX { get; private set; }
        public static int MaxY { get; private set; }

        public static List<Position> ListPositions { get; private set; }
        public static List<Position> ListTreePositions {
            get
            {
                return ListPositions.Where(w => w.Agent?.Type == AgentType.Tree).ToList();
            }
        }
        public static List<Position> ListDronePositions
        {
            get
            {
                return ListPositions.Where(w => w.Agent?.Type == AgentType.Drone).ToList();
            }
        }
        public int PosX { get; private set; }
        public int PosY { get; private set; }
        public int PosZ;
        private static object services;

        public Agent Agent { get; private set; }

        public Position()
        {
            ListPositions = new List<Position>();
        }

        public static void SetMaxValues(int maxX, int maxY)
        {
            MaxX = maxX;
            MaxY = maxY;
        }

        public void FillNeighbours(int posX, int posY, int dim)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < dim; y++)
                {
                    new Position(posX - (dim - y), posY - (dim - i), Agent);
                }
            }
        }
        public static Position CreateNewRandomPosition()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int rndX;
            int rndY;
            Position position = null;
            while (position == null)
            {
                rndX = rnd.Next(MaxX - 100);
                rndY = rnd.Next(MaxY - 100);
                position = CreatePosition(rndX, rndY);
            }
            return position;
        }

        public static Bitmap ExportBitmap()
        {
            return ExportBitmap(0, 0, MaxX, MaxY, ListPositions);
        }
        public static Bitmap ExportBitmap(int posX, int posY, int maxX, int maxY)
        {
            var listPositions = ListPositions.Where(w => (w.Agent != null) && (w.PosX >= posX && w.PosX <= maxX) && (w.PosY >= posY && w.PosY <= maxY)).ToList();
            return ExportBitmap(posX, posY, maxX, maxY, listPositions);
        }
        public static Bitmap ExportBitmap(int posX, int posY, int maxX, int maxY, AgentType agentType)
        {
            var listPositions = ListPositions.Where(w => (w.Agent.Type == agentType) && (w.PosX >= posX && w.PosX <= maxX) && (w.PosY >= posY && w.PosY <= maxY)).ToList();
            return ExportBitmap(posX, posY, maxX, maxY, listPositions);
        }
        public static Bitmap ExportBitmap(int posX, int posY, int maxX, int maxY, AgentType[] agentType)
        {
            var listPositions = ListPositions.Where(w => (agentType.Contains(w.Agent.Type)) && (w.PosX >= posX && w.PosX <= maxX) && (w.PosY >= posY && w.PosY <= maxY)).ToList();
            return ExportBitmap(posX, posY, maxX, maxY, listPositions);
        }
        private static Bitmap ExportBitmap(int posX, int posY, int maxX, int maxY, List<Position> positions)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(maxX - posX, maxY - posY);
            if (Agent.Sprites.Count() == 0)
            {
                Agent.LoadSprites();
            }
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

            foreach (var item in positions)
            {
                var SpriteWidth = Agent.Sprites[item.Agent.Type].Width / 2;
                var SpriteHeight = Agent.Sprites[item.Agent.Type].Height / 2;
                g.DrawImage(Agent.Sprites[item.Agent.Type], new Point(item.PosX - SpriteWidth - posX, item.PosY - SpriteHeight - posY));
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists("Photos"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("Photos");
            }
            int count = Directory.GetFiles("Photos", "*").Length;
            bmp.Save("Photos\\Img" + count + 1 + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            return bmp;
        }
        public Position(int poxX, int poxY)
        {
            PosX = poxX;
            PosY = poxY;
            if (Agent != null)
                ListPositions.Add(this);
        }
        public Position(int posX, int posY, Agent agent)
        {
            PosX = posX;
            PosY = posY;
            Agent = agent;
            if (Agent != null)
                ListPositions.Add(this);
        }
        public void AssociateAgent(Agent agent)
        {
            Agent = agent;
            if (Agent != null)
                ListPositions.Add(this);
        }
        public static bool CheckPositionIsValid(int poxX, int poxY)
        {
            int? NullableMaxX = MaxX;
            int? NullableMaxY = MaxY;
            var posXValid = poxX > 0 && (poxX <= MaxX || NullableMaxX == null); //verifies if posX is within the boundries of the premises
            var posYValid = poxY > 0 && (poxY <= MaxY || NullableMaxY == null); //verifies if posY is within the boundries of the premises
            return posXValid && posYValid; //returns if they are both valid
        }
        public static Position Find(int poxX, int poxY)
        {
            return ListPositions.Find(f => f.PosX == poxX && f.PosY == poxY) ?? null;
        }
        public static Position CreatePosition(int poxX, int poxY)
        {
            if (Find(poxX, poxY) == null)
                if (CheckPositionIsValid(poxX, poxY))
                    return new Position(poxX, poxY);
                else
                    return null;
            else
                return null;
        }
        public Dictionary<int, Position> ListNeighbourPositions(int dim = 1)
        {
            Dictionary<int, Position> NeighbourList = new Dictionary<int, Position>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (i != 5)
                {
                    var position = FindNeighbour(i, dim);
                    if (position != null)
                        NeighbourList.Add(i, position);
                }
            }
            return NeighbourList;
        }
        public Position FindNeighbour(int neighbourPos, int dim)
        {
            var position = FindNeighbourbyPosition(neighbourPos, dim);
            return Find(position.Item1, position.Item2);
        }
        public Tuple<int, int> FindNeighbourbyPosition(int neighbourPos, int dim = 1)
        {
            int neighbourPosX;
            int neighbourPosY;

            switch (neighbourPos)
            {
                case 1:
                    neighbourPosX = PosX - dim;
                    neighbourPosY = PosY - dim;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    neighbourPosX = PosX;
                    neighbourPosY = PosY - dim;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    neighbourPosX = PosX + dim;
                    neighbourPosY = PosY - dim;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    neighbourPosX = PosX - dim;
                    neighbourPosY = PosY;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    neighbourPosX = PosX + dim;
                    neighbourPosY = PosY;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    neighbourPosX = PosX - dim;
                    neighbourPosY = PosY + dim;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    neighbourPosX = PosX;
                    neighbourPosY = PosY + dim;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    neighbourPosX = PosX + dim;
                    neighbourPosY = PosY + dim;
                    break;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
            return new Tuple<int, int>(neighbourPosX, neighbourPosY);
        }
        public void UpdatePosition(int newX, int newY)
        {
            PosX = newX;
            PosY = newY;
        }
        public static void Serialize()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists("Serialized"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("Serialized");
            }
            int count = Directory.GetFiles("Serialized", "*").Length;

            string fileName = "Serialized/PositionsSerialized_" + count + ".json";
            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListPositions, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            });
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, jsonString);
        }

        public static void Deserialize()
        {
            if (Directory.Exists("Serialized"))
            {
                var FileName = "Serialized/PositionsSerialized_4.json";
                var JsonString = File.ReadAllText(FileName);                
                ListPositions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Position>>(JsonString);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("There's no directory");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The JSON you've shown isn't a list of anything. It's a JSON object - but it's also malformed. Please provide a [mcve] rather than just bits and pieces.

Comment: @JonSkeet that is the most minimalistic I can get ATM tho. And it's fresh as well

Comment: The way I serialzied it was ```string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListPositions, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            });
```
Being ListPositions the list I am trying to deserialize now, after the program is reset and the list is empty.

Comment: You really can't provide a complete example with fewer than 58 lines of JSON? And you can't provide a *complete* piece of JSON? (I don't believe that the result of calling `SerializeObject` really ended with a trailing comma. I also strongly expect that the result of serializing a list *actually* started with `[` and ended with `]`. I also believe you could include a `Position` class to make it a complete example, and move your code into a standalone program. With C# 6, it's trivial to do that without any cruft.)

Comment: @JonSkeet well that is what happened. Im not making it up. Do you need the full Json? The rest of the items fall from the same type of structure, just different values. I guess I could provide a smaller example, yes.

Comment: @JonSkeet I will add the full Position class then

Comment: @JonSkeet I might add that I'm using DAG trees

Comment: "Do you need the full Json?" Well we need *complete* JSON, yes. I still find it very hard to believe that a list was actually serialized as a single object, or that Json.NET left a trailing comma at the end of the JSON. I'd be happy to believe it if you had a complete example that would reproduce that, of course - but we don't have one at the moment. And of course, as expected, the problem ended up being in the code you hadn't shown us. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for suggestions on how to write good questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of your problem is because you defined setters as private...

```
    public static int MaxX { get; private set; }
    public static int MaxY { get; private set; }
    public int PosX { get; private set; }
    public int PosY { get; private set; }
```

it should be...

```
    public static int MaxX { get; set; }
    public static int MaxY { get; set; }
    public int PosX { get; set; }
    public int PosY { get; set; }
```